# C - Store Structs in Array confusion

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pebble-watch

Good morning,
I am currently working on an app for Pebble Smartwatch which uses standard C, a language I just started with.

I have a function that adds a Money Transaction to an array. I have defined Transaction like this:

```
struct Transaction {
    char * title;
    char * amount;
    char * date;
    char * text;
} txnsArray[20];
```

whenever I receive a transaction it is added to the  txnsArray using this function:

```
void addTransaction(DictionaryIterator * txnIter){
    Tuple *txnTitle_Tuple = dict_find(txnIter, TRANSACTION_TITLE);
    Tuple *txnAmount_Tuple = dict_find(txnIter, TRANSACTION_AMOUNT);
    Tuple *txnText_Tuple = dict_find(txnIter, TRANSACTION_TEXT);


    txnsArray[transOverview.txnCounter].title = txnTitle_Tuple->value->cstring;
    txnsArray[transOverview.txnCounter].amount = txnAmount_Tuple ->value->cstring;
    txnsArray[transOverview.txnCounter].text = txnText_Tuple->value->cstring;

    transOverview.txnCounter++;

}
```

Now when I check this array it does add entries as it is supposed to, however the last transaction I add applies to all entries.

Say I first add a transaction wight he amount 2.5 € and then another one with 4.0€ then both entries will have 4.0€.

What am I doing wrong? Help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: This code has a whiff of possible _undefined behaviour_ about it. Try `txnsArray[transOverview.txnCounter].amount = malloc(strlen(txnAmount_Tuple ->value->cstring) + 1); strcpy(txnsArray[transOverview.txnCounter].amount,txnAmount_Tuple ->value->cstring);` to ensure the _char_ values are actually copied, and not just the mem-addresses are assigned

Comment: yup! that was it. thank you so much :]

Comment: Well, I went on ahead and posted the comment as answer to your question. May be worth reading though, as I suggest you _don't_ use `strcpy`, in favour of `memcpy` or, if needs must, `strncpy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `dict_find` function does not allocate memory for `value->cstring` but uses the same buffer for each call. So the structs in your array end up with pointers to the same memory, and if `dict_find` modifies it, it modifies all array entries.